# How to solve fatal error

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming, fatal-error

My website is showing:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 64 bytes) in
>   /home/s1079227/public_html/wp-content/themes/construction/inc/options/inc/fields/typography/googlefonts.php
>   on line 1

I want to solve it.

website Name:http://www.xcelcc.com.au/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, you just need to tell WordPress to increase the limit. To do that, edit the `wp-config.php` for your site and add a line like this one; add it after the opening

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

If the error comes when restoring/migrating, then you should also add this (which allows even more memory to the admin dashboard):

```
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '384M');
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to increase memory limit
First you need to edit the wp-config.php file on your WordPress site. It is located in your WordPress site’s root folder, and you will need to use an FTP client or file manager in your web hosting control panel.
Next, you need to paste the following code in wp-config.php file just before the line that says ‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging.’

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add this line in your wp-config.php file:
`define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`
it will increase your memory size.